# Problema con registro y login de usuarios en flask

Tags: python, flask

hola necesito una opinion estoy desarrollando una api rest con python flask
**pero tengo un pequeño problema con una clase**
mi codigo esta modularizado en partes para mas flexibilidad de funciones en la api 
pero al momento de registrar y logear usuarios esta clase funciona de manera correcta incluso si la ejecuto en modo consola.
le problema es al usar en el momento con el servidor activo la funcion de la clase me retorna none y deja de funcionar la api 
aqui les dejo el codigo de la clase para que me brinden su opinion aqui el codigo completo [GitHub repositorio.](https://github.com/Herd25/LinusGems)

```
class TokenUser(object):
    """ @classname global functions return @void """
    def __init__(self):
        super(TokenUser, self).__init__()
        # Method construct class name
        self._name_patron = re.compile(r'\W.')
        self._username_patron = re.compile(r'\b^[a-zA-Z]{0,1}\b')
        self._email_patron = re.compile(r'\b[\w.%+-]+@[\w.-]+\.(com|net|org)\b')

    def _queryAdmin(self, *data):
        # Method query database username
        self._username = data[0]
        self._password = data[1]
        # Validate fields
        if not self._username:
            flash('Llena un usuario', 'alert')
        elif not self._password:
            flash('Digita la contraseña', 'alert')
        else:
            self._query_admin = User.query.filter_by(username=self._username, email=self._username).first()
            # validate query
            if self._query_admin and self._query_admin.check_password(self._password):
                flash('Bienvenido {}'.format(self._query_admin.username), 'sucess')
                session['username'] = self._query_admin
                return redirect(url_for('admin', _external = True))
            else:
                flash('contraseña invalida o usuario no existe', 'alert')
                print('error en el metodo')
        return jsonify(data)

    def _createAdmin(self, *data):
        # Method create admin user
        self._name = data[0]
        self._username = data[1]
        self._email = data[2]
        self._password1 = data[3]
        self._password2 = data[4]

        # Validate fields

        if not self._name and self._username and self._email and self._password1 and self._password2:
            flash('Todos los campos deben estar llenos', 'alert')
        else:
            if not self._name_patron.findall(self._name):
                flash('El nombre contiene caracteres no permitidos', 'alert')
            elif not self._username_patron.match(self._username):
                flash('El nombre de usuario de contener al menos una letra mayuscula', 'alert')
            elif not self._email_patron.findall(self._email):
                flash('Correo electronico no valido', 'alert')
            elif not self._password1 == self._password2:
                flash('Las contraseñas ingresadas no coinciden', 'alert')
            else:
                self._password = self._password2
                # Create new user
                newuser = User(self._name, self._username, self._email)
                newuser.password_hash(self._password)
                newuser.save()
                # Send Message from suscribe
                newuser.send(self._email)
                flash('Registro exitoso verifica tu correo y confirma tu registro', 'sucess')
                return redirect(url_for('admin'))
```

Comment: He echado un vistazo a tu repositorio y he visto algo raro, que quizás (o quizás no) es la causa de tu problema. En todo caso no parece estar bien. En el archivo en que defines las rutas, la definición de las rutas `/login` y `/SignUp` hacen una extraña redirección. Compruebas si el método es POST y si no, rediriges a la misma ruta. Esto causará un bucle infinito de redirecciones GET y el navegador acabará por detectarlo y abortar.

Comment: bueno si vi ese detalle pero

Comment: y lo corregi solo que olvide actualizar lo que paa esque aun asi me devuelve none la clase

Comment: sera acaso que no se puede instanciar clases propias para validar y que esta me devuelva el json que requiero para poder entara a la aera restringida